# scp or pscp transfer files to ssh machine but not showing any copied files in machine

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer, scp, pscp

I am using putty ssh client in windows to login to remote machine

I transfer files using scp and pscp from my local to server

scp:

```
scp -r script-1/ root@104.130.169.111:/mounarajan/script-1
```

Response in command line:

```
artist_dedup_urls1                            100%  414KB 413.8KB/s   00:00    
reverbnation_crawler.py                       100%   21KB  21.0KB/s   00:00
```

pscp:

```
pscp -r script-1/ root@104.130.169.111:/mounarajan/script-1
```

Response in command line:

```
artist_dedup_urls1        | 413 kB | 413.8 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
reverbnation_crawler.py   | 21 kB |  21.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

But after this the `script-1` folder in server machine is empty.

Where is the problem actaully?

Comment: Is their a script-1 directory at /mounarajan/ ?

Comment: yeah there is a script -1 directory

Comment: But the problem is there is not script - 2 directory but if i give mounarajan/script-2/ that also works....but it should not work actually

Comment: What is script-2 directory. As per your command script-1 directory shall be created in your server  **inside**   `mounarajan/script-1/`

Comment: ok the file transfer is successful in command line but i could not see any files in server?

Comment: I am using putty ssh client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you deleted the "script-1" on 104.130.169.111 before? Your situation seems to be the same as this scenario:

1. On command window 1: cd to certain directory, say "a/b/c"
2. On *another window*: delete "a/b/c", recreate it and copy in some files
3. On command window 1: no change can be seen.

Solution is: on command window 1, cd to another directory and then cd back to "a/b/c" again to access the *newly created* directory